# Insert plots with one column in two colum

Tags: graphics, xetex

I need to insert some plots with one column in two-column style and show in the mid.
I want to show this:

```
\begin{figure*}[!h]
.................
pic
.................
\end{figure*}
```

I found the command !h not work.
It shows like this:

```
...........
...........
```

Last page:
pic

I use the IEEE journal paper style.
Many thanks.

Comment: Hello ! Welcome on TeX ! Please have a look on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and give us a MWE

Comment: It's my fault, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The `stfloats` package, from the `sttools` bundle allows the use of the `[b]` placement option. Just like with `[t]`, most of the time, floats will be placed at the bottom of the  *next* page.

As to the `[h]` placement, you can have a work-around with the `cuted` package, from the same bundle. It defines the `strip` environment which end the current line, then interrupts the two-column mode (restored after `\end{strip}`). However, it is not a float, and you can't use the `figure` or `table` environment  inside it, hence supposing you want a centred float, you have to code something like:

```
\begin{strip}
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{...}
    ...............
   \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}Some caption}
\end{strip}
```

The `\captionof` command is defined either by the small package `capt-of` or by the more general `caption`.